# API to get android google play Xp user xperience

Tags: android, google-play-services

I need to create a game application on Android,
and I need to take user information with API of Google+.

How I can take this information?
What's Api for this?

If possible, I can see xp account of google play?
I need to create an account manager, after connexion of user, information of Googleplay Xp are visible.

Can you help me to know if its possible?
Thank you

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It will still depend on your implementation but you can check the documentation - [Setting Up Google Play Games Services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling)

> Earning experience points (XP)
>
> Players can gain levels on their Game Profile when they earn achievements in Play Games enabled games. For every [point](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/achievements#points) associated with an achievement, the player gains 100 experience points (XP) when they earn that achievement. In other words:

```
XP for an achievement = 100 * (point value for the achievement)
```

> Play Games services keeps track of the XP earned by each player and sends out a notification to the [Google Play Games app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.play.games) when the player has earned enough points to 'level up'. Players can view their level and XP history from their Profile page in the Google Play Games app.

The documentation will guide you in setting up your game with Google Play Games, it will also serve as a guide in accessing the API and sign-in authentication.

Hope this helps.